# CloudKit or something like CoreData

Tags: core-data, local-storage, cloudkit

I want to create a app where the user can save data, but the user should be able to share this data with others. My question is, would you use CloudKit or something like CoreData. Or would you save the data locally and when the user wants to share it push it to CloudKit.

And does the user can use the app offline when he has data sharing with other activated. Is there something like caching?

Thanks for your help!

My problem is that I am unsure how to setup something like this, would to have some advice!